# Perform measure calculation with the saql compact form

Tags: einstein-analytics, saql

for the step clause "measures" using the saql compact form, is possible to make arithmetical calculation like sum(AMOUNT)/sum(WEIGHT) without a compare table? The following example explain what i mean:

```
"measures": {
    ["sum","AMOUNT"],
    "/",
    ["sum","WEIGHT"]
}
```

I know that this example is totally wrong, but it deserve me to explain more in details my questions.

Thank you!

Comment: I forget to specify that the result of the calculation will be the grouping clause

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with SOQL directly.

What you can do is add a formula field to make the calculation, however I do not believe it can be grouped so after that use a WFR to populate a number field with the value from the formula field. Then you can use that in the grouping.

Sometimes the simplest things require many steps.

Answer (score 0):

Eric is correct,

Calculations must currently be done in SAQL or in a compare table, which has a different syntax

Thanks